# Approach for parsing json string with different type of objects

Tags: c#, json, parsing, jsonfx

I have following json string

```
{
    "serverTime": "2013-08-12 02:45:55,558",
    "data": [{
        "key1": 1,
        "result": {
            "sample1": [""],
            "sample2": "test2"
        }
    },{
        "key1": 1,
        "result": {
            "sample3": [""],
            "sample4": "test2"
        }
    }]
}
```

Using [JSONTOC#](http://json2csharp.com/)

Following classes are generated.

```
public class Result 
{
    public List<string> sample1 { get; set; }
    public string sample2 { get; set; }
    public List<string> sample3 { get; set; }
    public string sample4 { get; set; } 
} 

public class Datum 
{
    public int key1 { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; } 
}

public class RootObject 
{
    public string serverTime { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; } 
}
```

As one can see the tool has generated **Result** class with all the possible properties.

I am trying to following approach to parse the json

```
public class Response<T>
{
    public Date serverTime;
    public ResponseData<T>[] data;
}

public class ResponseDataBase
{
    public int key1;
}

public class ResponseData<T> : ResponseDataBase
{
    public T result;
}
```

Here can **T** be following two classes

```
Class Result1
{
   public List<string> sample1 { get; set; }
   public string sample2 { get; set; }
}

Class Result2
{
    public List<string> sample3 { get; set; }
    public string sample4 { get; set; }
}
```

I have these class declaration as reference, the class definition can be totally different.

** How can I parse this json by specifying Result type.** I am using JSONFx.net for deserializing back to objects.

Thanks

Comment: in json.net we use converters in such cases. maybe you want to make your question more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Classes generated from your JSON data:

```
public class Result
{
    public List<string> sample1 { get; set; }
    public string sample2 { get; set; }
}

public class Datum
{
    public int key { get; set; }
    public Result result { get; set; }
}

    public class RootObject
    {
    public string serverTime { get; set; }
    public List<Datum> data { get; set; }
}
```

User Newtonsoft.Json dll to Deserialize JSON data like:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>("yourjsonstring");
```

then you can use properties of obj like:

```
var date = DateTime.Parse(obj.serverTime);
```

and so on.